# Meteor, rendering markdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am building a Meteor site and want to allow users to edit in markdown and collaborate using github. I have a Meteor template with the standard boilerplate around the markdown but instead of having it inline in the page, I'd like to automatically read in the markdown content like a partial in other frameworks.

So if my template is:

```
// pages/page1.html
<template name="page_name">
{{#markdown}}

# Some markdown...

{{/markdown}}
</template>
```

How can I read a particular page's markdown into the template replacing the above `# Some markdown...` with the contents of /pages/page1.md? If I use partials I need to change the router, etc.

Can someone advise how to do approach this? I will have many markdown pages and being new to Meteor am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The trick for doing this is to extend Meteor's templating. I'm too new at Meteor but never fear, there's a package for it: [markdow-templating](https://atmospherejs.com/simple/markdown-templating). This allows anyone to use markdown and/or html for templates. Inside the markdown you can have partials, or variables just like an html template only they can also be defined in markdown—nice.

In my use case I created a subdirectory which is tied to a docs repo on github. Then any user can put up a PR for a doc change or fix and if I accept the PR it is auto-deployed to the site. Since it is a full fledged template it is also reactively updated.

So my markdown page template is:

```
{{#template name='page_1'}}
# page 1

#**Markdown only**

# Lorem Ipsum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do ...

{{/template}}
```

See the Atmosphere and github docs for more options including embedded templates (partials) and variables.